# snake game snake not appearing when adding movement code

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I was following a tutorial from youtube for developing the snake game.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXGwSp28DlE&list=PLJSII25WrAz6d_vfRsMGU2SG_e_x8ajtX&index=2

I am having a problem creating the snake body. According to the tutor we need to add `g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);` for the movement of the snake in the module `public void paint(Graphics g)`.

But when I add this the snake does not appear in my screen. I've followed the tutor as it is, but I am getting the problem. Please help me.

```
//Screen.java
package game.graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import entities.BodyParts;

public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable{ 
    public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;    
    private BodyParts b;
    private ArrayList<BodyParts> snake; 
    private int ticks;  
    private int X = 10, Y = 10, size = 5;
    private boolean right = false, left = true, up=false, down = false;

    public Screen()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));     
        snake = new ArrayList<BodyParts>();
        Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "game loop");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void tick()
    {
        if(snake.size() == 0)
        {
            b = new BodyParts(X, Y, 10);
            snake.add(b);
        }
        ticks++;

        if(ticks > 2500)
        {
            //check the direction of movement
            if(right) {X++;}
            if(left) {X--;}
            if(up) {Y++;}
            if(down) {Y--;}

            ticks = 0;

            b = new BodyParts(X, Y, 10);
            snake.add(b);

            if(snake.size() > size)
            {
                snake.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        //g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        for(int i = 0;i<WIDTH/10 ;i++)
        {
            g.drawLine(i*10, 0, i*10, HEIGHT);
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<HEIGHT/10 ;i++)
        {
            g.drawLine( 0, i*10, WIDTH, i*10);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < snake.size() ;i++)
        {
            snake.get(i).draw(g);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(running)
        {
            tick();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
// BodyParts.java
package entities;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class BodyParts {    
    private int X, Y, width, height;
    public BodyParts(int X, int Y, int tile)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        width = tile;
        height = tile;
    }   
    public void tick()
    {

    }   
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(X*width, Y*height, width, height);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(X*width + 2, Y*height + 2, width-4, height-4);

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to use `clear`, if you were to honour the established paint chain. Instead of overriding `paint`, override `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent` before you do anything else, it will update your UI for you

Comment: Sorry I can not understand what you say. I am novice in java, please can you elaborate it more. Thank You!!!

Comment: Then you need to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to gain a better understanding of how the painting process. You also have a synchronization issue, which is leading to a potential race condition between your update thread and the main event/paint thread (which cause at least two null pointer exceptions when I was testing)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your response. Please can you tell me how can I test my console application in ECLIPSE. Are there any good tutorials for this.

Comment: Debugging is bit of an art form, but you should start by adding in log messages (`System.out.println`) at points in your code to output various states, for example, I found that your `tick` loop is forever decreasing `X` each time, so new parts are been placed off the screen. Depending on which IDE you're using will depend on which tutorual will help you

Comment: Ah, okay, I think I know what's going on. Every `tick`, the `X` property is been decremented, every 2500 ticks, you add a new body part, when the body is beyond a give size, you remove the head, so, even before the UI has had a chance to get on the screen, the snake has moved off the screen. Basically, your update loop is WAY too fast and your "ticks" count is meaningless as it's not based on any base value (other the how fast the CPU can process the thread).

Comment: Try adding `Thread.sleep(16)` (60 fps) at the end of your `tick` or `run` method and change `2500` to something like `16` and then you watch snake leave the screen